# Using Selenium IDE Variables in Date Commands

Tags: javascript, selenium

I want to use Selenium IDE Variables in my Date Commands

I have quite a few jumbled commands (Which I'm sure aren't the best way of doing something), and have come up with the following **one line of syntax**

```
store | javascript{var d = new Date (); d.setDate (11); d.setMonth (2); d.setFullYear (2005); ( d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear() );} | test334
```

This gets me an output (In datetime format) in British.

When I switch the following portion of syntax from

```
d.setDate (11);
```

to

```
d.setDate (${depDay});
```

It gives me an error relating to ")" which I have tried adding in various spaces (As well as spacing the variable out more

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the second code snippet?

Comment: Instead of me setting the date using the NUMBER 11. I want to set date using the VARIABLE 11 (or 23 or 35 or who knows).

Comment: Okay, the way you wrote that code block was unclear. I've submitted an edit which makes it read a lot better.

Comment: This being said, the spaces don't matter (except when separating numbers, keywords, or names of things). I'm just not sure what that last line of Javascript is doing: `( d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear() );` results in the creation of a string, but how is that rendered as output from the Javascript block?

Comment: Never mind, if that part works, then don't change it. Yeah, I'm concerned that when using a Javascript block, you may not be able to use Selenium IDE variables, but I can't find anything to confirm or deny that.

Comment: That code snippet you pulled creates a Date parameter in the "English way" so DD/MM/YYYY, which is the way most people use it. As opposed to YYYY-DD-MM-Hours-min-secs-timezone

Thanks for the Edit, I'm new here and my background is maths, not coding as such.

Essentially I want to use a variable from selenium yes. It only says I'm missing brackets, so I must be close I figure